# How to change Resource Dictionary Color in the runtime

Tags: c#, wpf

In XAML:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <Color x:Key="BrushColor1">Red</Color>
    <Color x:Key="BrushColor2">Black</Color>

    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="GradientBrush1" StartPoint="0,0.5" EndPoint="1,0.5">
        <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource BrushColor2}" Offset="0" />
        <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource BrushColor1}" Offset="1" />
    </LinearGradientBrush>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

In C#:

```
    public void CreateTestRect()
    {
        Rectangle exampleRectangle = new Rectangle();
        exampleRectangle.Width = 150;
        exampleRectangle.Height = 150;
        exampleRectangle.StrokeThickness = 4;
        exampleRectangle.Margin = new Thickness(350);

        ResourceDictionary resources = this.Resources;
        resources["BrushColor1"] = Colors.Pink;
        resources["BrushColor2"] = Colors.RoyalBlue;
        Brush brush =(Brush)this.FindResource("GradientBrush1");

        exampleRectangle.Fill = brush;
        canvas.Children.Insert(0, exampleRectangle);
    }
```

How to change those Color elements in the runtime in C#. The LinearGradientBrush should get changed dynamically?

I wish to do something like this:

```
(Color)(this.FindResource("BrushColor1")) = Colors.Pink;
```

but I failed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can directly overwrite the value in the resource dictionary.

For example:

```
ResourceDictionary resources = this.Resources; // If in a Window/UserControl/etc
resources["BrushColor1"] = System.Windows.Media.Colors.Black;
```

That being said, I would normally recommend not doing this.  Instead, I would have two sets of colors, each with their own key, and use some mechanism to switch which color is assigned to your values at runtime instead.  This lets you leave the entire logic for this in the xaml itself.

Comment: I tried, but still I cannot change color on my canvas. Anyway, thank u.

Comment: @XiaoruiDong That won't work - you need to find the actual resource dictionary storing it to change it.

Comment: I just solved it. Looks like only **LinearGradientBrush** does not support     **DynamicResource**. The rest brushes like **SolidColorBrush** supports it.

Answer (score 3):

I just solved it. Looks like only **LinearGradientBrush** does not support **DynamicResource** for color. Even u overwrite the dynamic color, the **LinearGradientBrush** itself won't get updated. PS: **SolidColorBrush** supports runtime color change. Do something below instead:

```
LinearGradientBrush linearGradientBrush = (LinearGradientBrush)(this.FindResource("GradientBrush1"));
linearGradientBrush.GradientStops[0].Color = color1;
linearGradientBrush.GradientStops[1].Color = color2;
```

If the **LinearGradientBrush** is hidden in a nested complex brush defined in Resource Dictionary, you make the **LinearGradientBrush** emerged, and assign a key to it.